# Html to canvas background color wraps incorrectly

Tags: html, css, canvas, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas.js 0.4.1 to convert a DOM to canvas for printing.  When the text has a background color on a span, and the span wraps to the next line, then the canvas version covers the whole rectangle of the 2 wrapping lines.  It doesn't just cover the text.  Furthermore it hides the text in the prior span.

The following fiddle demonstrates it pretty well.  The 'one one' span is completely covered up by the blue background on the 'two two' span.

https://jsfiddle.net/sddah9k2/1/

css:

```
#content {
  width:200px;
}
.select {
  background-color:#3efcdb
}
```

html:

```
<div id='content'>
<span >one one one one one one </span>
<span class="select" >two two two two two two </span>
<span >three three three three three </span>
</div>

<div id="img-out"></div>
```

code:

```
html2canvas($("#content"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
```

My theory is html2canvas can't tell what the bounding box of the spans are, or maybe it just doesn't support multiple rectangles as bounds.

Is there any type of CSS effect I can use on the HTML text that will render correctly in html2canvas?  It doesn't have to be a background color, but I have to somehow indicate that the wrapping span is highlighted.

Comment: Yes it seems that background-color on inline elements doesn't work well. There is already [an issue](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/548) on project's github page. Note also that on the latest version, there have been some improvements : https://jsfiddle.net/sddah9k2/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas does not support multi line inline texts. So your libraries splits it up, but the wrapping `.select` box gets the dimensions like an inline-block element.

You need to split and wrap every highlighted word with a seperate span.

**JS:**

```
var $selected = $('#content.notupdated .select');
$selected.each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var words = $this.text().split(" ");
    $this.empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
        $this.append($("<span>").text(v + ' '));
    });
});
$('#content.notupdated').removeClass('notupdated').addClass('updated');
```

I updated you fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/sddah9k2/7/
I even updated [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061430/html-to-canvas-background-color-wraps-incorrectly/37068551#comment61673633_37061430)s improved fiddle of yours: https://jsfiddle.net/sddah9k2/6/ (I worked primarily on that one)

Comment: I figured out this morning that I could split on every letter, but every word is better since it will only wrap on space.  It also works to make display inline-block but then it wraps differently.

Answer (score 0):

I already accepted Seika85 answer since his was the first.  Here is what I ended up with, retaining the original span and also to do this for every 'select' span:

link:
https://jsfiddle.net/sddah9k2/9/

js:

```
// Get all the select spans
$('span.select').each(function (ix, block) {
    // split the text spans on word so it wraps in the same place
    var txtar = $(block).text().split(' ');

    // Remove the class on the outer span, but keep it intact.
    $(block).removeClass('select');
    $(block).html(''); // empty it
    // Replace each word.  Note the space before closing span!
    $(txtar).each(function (ix, txt) {
        $(block).append($('<span class="bg">'+txt+' </span>'));
    });
});
```

css:

```
.select {
   background-color:#3efcdb;
}
.bg {
   background-color:#3efcdb;  
}
```

Comment: You can shorten your CSS down to `.select, .bg { background-color:#3efcdb; }`. Whenever you would like to change the bg-color, you would have to do it only a single time.  
The same goes for your JS. The most editing jQuery methods always return *this*, so you can shorten *remove class* and *emtpy block* down to a single line: `$(block).removeClass('select').html('');`

Comment: In my application the css for 'select' comes from a different application, that I don't control, which is why I wanted my own class.  Your point about jquery line is well-taken though!  Cold be one line.